# C/C++ Реентрабельность функций обработки сигналов

Tags: c++, c, signal

Итак, есть такое понятие, как реентрабельность функции.
При обработке сигналов в linux возникают проблемы.
Например, на `SIGUSR1` я должен прочитать файл, и вызвать виртуальный метод, передав туда его содержимое.

```
void sigusr1_handler(int signum)
{
    std::string msg = read_sigmsg(get_sigmsg_filename());
    g_bootstraped->signal_handler(signum, msg); // виртуальный метод из глобального объекта
}
```

`std::string` является нереентрабельным, т.к. использует операторы `new` и `delete`, которые тоже нереентрабельные.

Я придумал три решения:

1. Из обработчика сигнала запускать поток, в котором проделать вышеприведенные операции.
   Но у меня вопрос: решит ли это проблему реентрабельности? В теории должно, ведь реентрабельность - это про один и тот же поток. Но придется требовать от наследников моего класса потокобезопасности.
2. Использовать отдельный поток, в котором через системный вызов `sigwait()` обрабатывать сигналы по очереди. Но тут уже не гарантируется реалтайм. Но не придется требовать от наследников моего класса потокобезопасности.
3. Не передавать сообщения через сигналы, а использовать другой способ межпроцессного взаимодействия. Оно менее предпочтительное, в силу того, что хотелось бы единообразия, для зарезервированного моей системой сигнала, который вызывает перезагрузку процесса, получившего его.

Хотелось бы критики этих решений.

Comment: Обычная практика подобного рода обработки сигналов заключается в том, что обработчик меняет exterm (или static) volatile переменную, а основной код выполняет действия при ее изменении

Answer (score 1):

Операторы `new` `delete` реентрабельные. Однако тут проблема посложнее, дело в том, что в обработчике асинхронных сигналов можно вызывать только функции из [категории `async-signal-safe`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html), а не просто `reentrant`. Соответственно создание потоков в обработчике не допускается. *не гарантируется реалтайм* - он не гарантируется в любом случае.

Вариант 3 с полным отказом от сигналов выглядит предпочтительно. Чем меньше приходится иметь дело с этими атавизмами, тем лучше.

Comment: "> Соответственно создание потоков в обработчике не допускается."

А если создать поток заранее? и следить в нём за событиями записи, а из обработчика сигнала делать эту запись?

Comment: @OlegUP, внимательно прочтите список signal-safe функций. Дуиаю, идея использования потоков (да и крестов тоже) сама собой отпадет

Comment: @OlegUP А если создать поток заранее и крутить его, то отпадает смысл в использовании сигнала вместо более обычных способов передачи сообщений.

Comment: @user7860670, традиционно демоны в \*nix читают обновление конфигурации (и .т.п.), по получению сигнала

Comment: @user7860670 Операторы `new` и `delete` не могут быть реентрабельными, потому что используют нереентрабельную `malloc`.